# Comparing performance of multi- and single - thread search of a maximum number

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class that compares the performance of two methods (multi- and single- thread) that searches for maximum number in the string of numbers. I want to improve the performance of a multithreaded variant because I think it can work more efficiently.

```
public class Part4 {

    private static String PATH = "part4.txt";
    private static String ENCODING = "Cp1251";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max1;
        int max2;

        String[] lines = Util.read(PATH, ENCODING).split(System.lineSeparator());

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        max1 = findMaxMT(lines);
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(max1);
        System.out.println(t2-t1);

        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        max2 = findMax(lines);
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(max2);
        System.out.println(t4-t3);

    }

    public static int findMaxMT(String[] lines) {

        int max;
        List<MaxFinder> threadList = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (String line : lines) {
            MaxFinder thread = new MaxFinder(line);
            thread.start();
            threadList.add(thread);
        }

        threadList.forEach(thread -> {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        threadList.forEach(thread -> {
            res.add(thread.getCurrentMax());
        });

        max = MaxFinder.maxFrom(res);

        return max;
    }

    public static int findMax(String[] lines) {

        List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
        int max;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
            int currentMax;

            for (String s : lines[i].split("\\s")) {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }

            currentMax = MaxFinder.maxFrom(numbers);

            res.add(currentMax);
        }

        max = MaxFinder.maxFrom(res);

        return max;
    }


}

class MaxFinder extends Thread {

    private String line;
    private int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public MaxFinder(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();

        for (String s : line.split("\\s")) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }

        currentMax = maxFrom(numbers);
    }


    public int getCurrentMax() {
        return currentMax;
    }

    public static int maxFrom(List<Integer> numbers) {

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int n : numbers) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
                if (n > max) {
                    max = n;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

`Thread.sleep(1)` is for benchmarking.